# Tkinter Not Showing Animated Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I want to show this matplotlib real-time graph in tkinter GUI
[Real-time Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd6Vw.png)

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root= tk.Tk()

style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    graph = open('data.txt','r').read()
    lines = graph.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []
    zs = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x, y, z = line.split(',')
            xs.append(float(x))
            ys.append(float(y))
            zs.append(float(z))
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys, zs)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)

app = (fig, root)
root.mainloop()
```

I tried the code above, but the GUI isn't show anything. What can I do to show that real-time graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my bad. I updated my code in this line:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
```

With this line:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
line2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
line2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
```

I got my answer now.